# Adding Rows to Table Layout Programmatically

Tags: android, tablelayout

Hi i would like to get a table layout to fill with the data of a XML when the activity first starts but im kind of a newbie so i really have no idea on how to do it if someone know how could i possibly do this

Answer (score 3):

You can add table row dynamically as

```
for(int i=0;i<youxmlArray.size();i++){
    // get a reference for the TableLayout
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.TableLayout01);
    // create a new TableRow
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    // create a new TextView for showing xml data
    TextView t = new TextView(this);
    // set the text to "text xx"
    t.setText( "YOUR XML DATA  HERE");
    // add the TextView  to the new TableRow
    row.addView(t);
    // add the TableRow to the TableLayout
    table.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
}
```

and Add a **TableLayout** in your xml layout as

```
<TableLayout 
android:id = "@+id/TableLayout01" 
android:layout_width = "fill_parent" 
android:layout_height = "wrap_content"   
android:stretchColumns = "0" >
   < TableRow android:id = "@+id/TableRow01" 
   android:layout_width = "wrap_content" 
   android:layout_height = "wrap_content" >
      < TextView android:id = "@+id/TextView01" 
        android:layout_width = "fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content" 
        android:text = "textfield 1-1" >
        </ TextView >
   </ TableRow >
</ TableLayout >
```

Comment: will it go through all the XML data until it reaches the last entry?

Comment: try it if u have any problem then post your code i will edit it